# How to set a TextBlock's font size to be a ratio of another font size property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock inside a custom user control that I would like to be slightly larger (maybe 7% larger) than the global font size property for that user control. I am unsure of the best way to go about this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

(Obviously this attempt is atrocious, but hopefully it helps visualize what I'm asking).

```
<TextBlock 
    x:Name="Title" 
    FontSize="{myUserControl.FontSize * 1.07}"> 
    Hello Custom User Control! 
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: add code behind that when the myUserControl.FontSize is changed you change this. Another way is a ValueConverter and bind it to that property as a parameter.

Comment: @kenny I am not sure how to reference in code behind when UserControl.FontSize is changed - I have looked for an OnFontSizeChanged method to override but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer (credit to @Kenny) is a simple converter that takes the user control font size as it's input.

Use in xaml:

```
<z:RatioConverter x:Key="AdjustTitleFontSizeConverter" Ratio="1.07" />

<TextBlock 
    x:Name="Title" 
    FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Converter={StaticResource AdjustTitleFontSizeConverter}"> 
    Hello Custom User Control! 
</TextBlock>
```

RatioConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class RatioConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Input santize first..
        return (System.Convert.ToDouble(value)) * this.Ratio;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Double Ratio
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(RatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RatioProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RatioProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Ratio", typeof(Double), typeof(RatioConverter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `ScaleTransform` with a desired scale factor.

In this example all TextBlock inherit FontSize=20 from parent Window (it is Dependency Property inheritance). Then I change FontSize to 22 for one TextBlock, and scale another (20 * 1.1 == 22). They look similar to me.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDemos.FontWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WpfDemos" Height="300" Width="300" FontSize="20">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!" FontSize="22"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Custom User Control!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/CalcBinding/ library for this.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use? Also, I would greatly prefer to not have to use an entire external library to solve such a small issue.

Comment: Examples are available here - https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding. Wpf doesn't provide such flexibility in Binding out of box. However you can make use of code behind to implement same but i personally avoid code behind for binding changes.